# How can I restart Bluetooth using terminal in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, bluetooth, big-sur

I have tried this, and it doesn't seem to work

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload) (-603946984)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload) (-603946984)}
```

I also tried restarting using `blueutil` but it doesn't seem to work either.

I have an issue with Bluetooth that only resolves by restarting the computer. I'd like to restart only the Bluetooth module, if possible.